# Behind a black hole

Tags: black-hole

Nothing can escape a black hole , not even light. But what if anything approaches a black hole from behind..... Correct me if I'm wrong!
Do black holes have front and back?
If yes then does they suck everything from both sides??

Answer (score 10):

A black hole is be a spherical object so it does not have a front or back.